# Which Gmail notification app will work with 14.04?

Tags: unity, email, notification

I tried using the Gmail webapp and unity mail, but neither of them light up the notification indicator (the envelope does not turn blue). Unity mail doesn't even show up in the messaging menu. What can be done to fix them, what are some alternatives?

Comment: I dont even have an "envelope" anymore so im not really sure what to use any more either :/

Answer (score 2):

[Mail Notification app](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mail-notification/) works for me.

> mail-notification works with system trays implementing the freedesktop.org System Tray Specification, such as the GNOME Panel Notification Area, the xfce4 Notification Area and the KDE System Tray.

I have tried *unity-mail* also, but no notifies at all. Tried with different accounts.

Comment: Google considers this app as insecure. [this warning](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gm-notify/+bug/692851/comments/12) comes for both `gm-notify` and `mail-notification`. both very similar programs. tested today.

Comment: That's (probably) because app doesn't use OAuth, but password directly.

Answer (score 1):

[Unity Mail](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/unity-mail/) works fine in my case, on Ubuntu 14.04, with a Gmail account.

Actually it is the only one that works for me, among all other applications I tried (GMail Notify, CheckGMail, Main Notification, etc.).

It shows notifications for new mails both on Unity's System Tray (inside the mail icon) and on the Application Launcher bar. Simple but it does what it has to do.

[image: System Tray]

[image: Application Launcher bar]

Comment: also needs extra access via https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps .

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Gnubiff](http://gnubiff.sourceforge.net/) notification app. You can directly install it from Ubuntu repositories. Once installed you can configure it as follows for the Gmail (replace the user with your Gmail username):

[image: Gnubiff Gmail configuration]